# Initializing a nested structure

Tags: c, structure

This is a problem from learn C the hardway. This is database management system in C
 I have three structures :-

```
 struct Address {
         int id;
         int set;
         char *name;
         char *email;
 };

 struct Database {
int rows;
    struct Address *row;
 };

 struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
 };
```

I trying to initialize the database structure. However I am getting a segfault

```
    void Database_create(struct Connection *conn, int no_of_rows)
    {
      int i = 0;
  conn->db->row_num = no_of_rows; 

      for(i = 0; i < conn->db->row_num; i++) {

      // make a prototype to initialize it
      struct Address addr;
      addr.id = i;
      addr.set = 0;

      // then just assign it
      conn->db->rows[i] = addr;
      }
  }
```

I've made another function which allocates memory to these structures.

```
     struct Connection *Database_open(const char *filename, char mode)
      {   
        struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
        if(!conn) die("Memory error");

    int number = conn->db->rows;

        conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
    if(!conn->db) die("Memory error");

        conn->db->row = malloc(sizeof(*conn->db->row) * number);
        if(!conn->db->row) die("Memory error");

        if(mode == 'c') {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "w");
        } else {
         conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+");

      if(conn->file) {
         Database_load(conn);
      }
   }

   if(!conn->file) die("Failed to open the file");

      return conn;
   }
```

valgrind says "Use of uninitialized value of size 4" in Database_open()

Could anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: why are you using `rows` as an array, when it is just an `int`?

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's causing the segfault.  Most likely `conn->db` isn't initialized or something

Comment: @Ajit you should include how you are calling `Database_create`

Comment: rows is the number of tuples of the table . I am passing it as an argument at main when I create the database.

Comment: The line `int number = conn->db->rows;` dereferences `conn->db` before it is accessed.  Presumably this is what valgrind is reporting.

Answer (score 1):

`db` in `Connection` and `row` in `Database` are uninitialised pointers.  You need to initialise them and provide storage for the structs they point to.

You can probably save some dynamic allocation by changing `Connection` to have its `Database` as a member rather than a pointer

```
struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database db;
 };
```

You need to allocate memory for the database rows

```
conn->db.row = malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(*conn->db.row));
```

`Database_create` would then look something like

```
int Database_create(struct Connection *conn, int no_of_rows)
{
    int i = 0;
    conn->db.rows = no_of_rows;
    conn->db.row = malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(*conn->db.row));
    if (conn->db.row == NULL) {
        /* out of memory */
        return 1;  /* indicate failure to caller */
    }
    for(i = 0; i < conn->db->rows; i++) {
        conn->db.row[i].id = i;
        conn->db.row[i].set = 0;
    }
    return 0; /* indicate success to caller */
}
```

Note that this assumes memory is already allocated for the `Connection`

Comment: unless I'm reading something wrong, `rows` is an int and not a pointer

Comment: sure, you may also want to include that he is using `rows` as a pointer in his code as well

Comment: I've made another function which allocates memory to these structures.